# Run controller test on two different Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm helping to migrate a Rails 2 app to Rails 4, and I have come in towards the end of the project. The Rails 2 app has no tests.

Obviously we need tests to make sure the Rails 4 app works, but we don't want to write the tests in Rails 2 syntax, and then go through the pain of migrating the tests to Rails 4. We currently use RSpec on other projects.

I thought of writing them in Rails 4 as feature tests, and using `Capybara.app_host` to re-route the requests to a running Rails 2 application instance. Problem is, that the application is an API, and Capybara is not meant for testing APIs.

Is there any way of routing RSpec controller tests to another server instance?

Comment: I don't believe so (but someone else may chime in). I do however think you should just write the tests for Rails 4 and be done with it. If the new apps behaves exactly as you need, why does it matter what the old app does?

Comment: One reason to write tests on the old version before moving to the new version is that the requirements for the old version aren't well understood and will be discovered while testing the old version. (I don't have a good answer for the actual question either.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments, and sorry for not seeing them earlier. We have taken up the project again and I think we have a solution. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the comments.

I think we have a plan. We tried to get cucumber and cucumber-api-steps running on our old project, but we realised that it was going to be hard work getting old gem versions to work nicely together.

The solution I'm trying now is using RSpec 1.3 and creating a `spec/requests` folder and adding controller tests to it.

I got this idea from a post from http://matthewlehner.net/rails-api-testing-guidelines/ - thanks Matthew. I don't see request specs in the docs until RSpec 2, so we make our controller tests pretty close to integration tests using `integrate_views`, then check the contents of the body returned by the controller.

As for the syntax, maybe we can include an `expect(..)` helper to return an object that calls `#should` from a `#to` method in the Rails 2 project and remove it when we port the Rails 4 project.